# json_encode() error output when i do an while loop to fetch the results in a array

Tags: php, json

from this php while loop i fetch the results in a array

```
$rows = array();
$result = mysqli_query($con,"call getProductVariationByID($name)");
//$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
   {
    $rows['Product'][] = $row;
   }
  echo json_encode($rows, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

the result is with this 'null' in the end :

```
        "post_mime_type": "",
        "comment_count": "0"
    }
  ]
}null
```

Comment: what is that extra `}` closing brace? a typo?

Comment: Why did someone vote this question up? It doesn't ask anything or indicate the error

Comment: the code is a part of an function in php

Comment: apparently something, like the result of a function, is echo'd immediately after the echo json_encode();

Answer (score 0):

I bet the function containing this code is echo'd in your main php script.

Comment: Should be a comment. But that's probably the reason from where this `null` comes from.

Comment: Well, it is the answer to his question where the null is coming from.

Comment: nope, when i try to print the array this 'null' doesn't appear.. only when i use json_encode();